# Conditional copy paste

Tags: macros, conditional-statements

Can anyone help me with a macro which does the following thing. I have datas in sheet 1 with headers and sheet 2 only with headers and there is no datas. I need a macro to search for the matching headers of sheet 1 and sheet 2 and copy paste datas into sheet 2. For eg: if sheet 1 & 2 has header invoice, then datas from sheet 1 should be pasted into sheet 2 under that header. But the problem is with the pasting of datas. The macro should paste each invoices leaving 3 rows from the next invoice. Similarly it should do for other headers that are present in Sheet2 Eg: (Sheet1) Invoice Inv Date Amount 251 5/5/14 125150 5656 10/8/14 85000

Sheet(2) Account GL Invoice Inv date DB xxxx 251 5/5/14

after 3 rows DB xxxx 5656 10/8/14

I checked with other macros, but not able to paste datas after 3 rows. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Note that you need to change the sheet name to "Source" and "Target" respectively.

```
Sub copyPaste()

    Dim srcColumnName As String
    Dim srcColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim srcRowIndex As Integer
    Dim trgtColumnName As String
    Dim trgtColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim trgtRowIndex As Integer
    Dim srcItemColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim trgtItemColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim srcItemName As String

    srcColumnIndex = 1
    srcRowIndex = 1

    Do While (1)

        trgtColumnIndex = 1
        trgtRowIndex = 1

        srcColumnName = Worksheets("Source").Cells(srcColumnIndex, srcRowIndex).Value

        'MsgBox ("Source Column Name: " + srcColumnName)

        If (srcColumnName = "") Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        Do While (1)

            trgtColumnName = Worksheets("Target").Cells(trgtColumnIndex, trgtRowIndex).Value

            'MsgBox ("Target Column Name: " + trgtColumnName)

            If (trgtColumnName = "") Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            srcItemColumnIndex = 2
            trgtItemColumnIndex = 2

            If (trgtColumnName = srcColumnName) Then

                Do While (1)

                    srcItemName = Worksheets("Source").Cells(srcItemColumnIndex, srcRowIndex).Value

                    'MsgBox ("Source Item : " + srcItemName)

                    If (srcItemName = "") Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If

                    Worksheets("Target").Cells(trgtItemColumnIndex, trgtRowIndex).Value = Worksheets("Source").Cells(srcItemColumnIndex, srcRowIndex).Value

                    srcItemColumnIndex = srcItemColumnIndex + 1
                    trgtItemColumnIndex = trgtItemColumnIndex + 3

                Loop

            End If

            trgtRowIndex = trgtRowIndex + 1

        Loop

        srcRowIndex = srcRowIndex + 1

    Loop

    MsgBox ("Program Completed successfully !!! ")

End Sub
```

Regards
Nirmalya

Comment: Hi Nirmalya, Thanks for the macro. But it is not showing any datas. I ran the macro, it shows Prrogram completed successfully, but no datas are pasted in target sheet. Please advise

Comment: Please put data in the source sheet in the correct columns as mentioned in your description. Also manually write the headers in the Target sheet. Then run the macro. Without the headers in the target sheet it will not work.